# R Shiny - Spinner is displayed before clicking on actionbutton

Tags: r, shiny, spinner

I would like to display a spinner after clicking on an `actionbutton` and before the `datatable` values are shown.

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)
library(shinycssloaders)


ui <- fluidPage(
  navbarPage("Query Tool",
             navbarMenu("Structures",
                        tabPanel("Structure Properties", fluid = TRUE,
                                 sidebarLayout(
                                   sidebarPanel(
                                     textInput("structure_id_properties", strong("Structure:"), value = ''),
                                     actionButton("run_properties", "Run Analysis", icon = icon("play"))),
                                   mainPanel(
                                     tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                                                 tabPanel("Data Table",br(), withSpinner(DTOutput("table_properties")))
                                     ))
                                 )))))


server <- function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$run_properties, {
    structure_id_properties <- "test"    
    output$table_properties <- renderDT ({data_output(sql_data)})
    output$query_properties <- renderText({properties_sql}) 
  })
}
```

I have tried several options (`renderUI`, `output$table_properties <- renderDT({NULL})`...) in vain.

Comment: If someone tries to run the code you have provided here, will it run? I have added the required libraries but still don't know what `data_output`, `sql_data`, `properties_sql`, `output$query_properties`  are? Please provide a minimal reproducible example that showcases your problem :)

Comment: `withSpinner` shows a spinner animation while an output is recalculating. Now in `DTOutput("table_properties")` will have no data until you click the button, So until you click the button, a spinner animation will continue. That's why you are facing such behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`output$table_properties <- renderDT({NULL})` won't work because `withSpinner` will show exactly when `renderDT` does not provide a n output that can be rendered as data table.

Here would be one way of doing it. In this case the the data for the table aren't generated inside `renderDT` but it uses a reactive value to allow access to the data from anywhere inside the server.

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)
library(shinycssloaders)


ui <- fluidPage(
  navbarPage("Query Tool",
             navbarMenu("Structures",
                        tabPanel("Structure Properties", fluid = TRUE,
                                 sidebarLayout(
                                   sidebarPanel(
                                     textInput("structure_id_properties", strong("Structure:"), value = ''),
                                     actionButton("run_properties", "Run Analysis", icon = icon("play"))),
                                   mainPanel(
                                     tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                                                 tabPanel("Data Table",
                                                          br(), 
                                                          withSpinner(DTOutput("table_properties")))
                                     ))
                                 )))))


server <- function(input, output) {
  data_output <- reactiveValues(sql_data = data.frame(test1 = character(), test2 = character(), test3 = integer()))
  
  observeEvent(input$run_properties, {
    data_output$sql_data <- NULL
    Sys.sleep(2.5) # for demo purposes
    data_output$sql_data <- data.frame(test1 = letters[1:5], test2 = LETTERS[1:5], test3 = 1:5)
  })
  output$table_properties <- renderDT ({req(data_output$sql_data)})
  
  output$query_properties <- renderText({properties_sql}) 
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```